# Is it possible to get one geometry per area/box in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis

I have millions of rows of geometry data. Some of them are close to each other (tens of meters apart), and some of them can be very far from each other. You can think of gas stations in real world where some gas stations are close to each other across the street, but some are not. The next closest one can be few hundreds meters or tens of kilometers apart.

I was curious if it is possible to write a query that can select one record per area. (either square area or in circle is fine)

For instance, a query that can do something like

"I want to select all gas stations in Germany but only interested in seeing at most one per 500m radius area. If there are multiple stations that are close to each other (fewer than 500m apart), only one of them must be selected."

=> In the result set of the query, I can safely assume that most of Germany's gas stations will be shown and none of them will be fewer than 500 meters apart.

One way that I thought of doing this is to calculate geohash for each geometry, and select one per certain geohash prefix. However, this approach is not very flexible because the query will be limited to geohash characters. I cannot supply arbitrary distance threshold in meters.

Would this be possible as PostGIS query? (e.g. using clustering approach perhaps?)

**Edit 1**

Below is an example incomplete query that I have tried using geohash. Results are sorted by geohash, so it is just matter of selecting one from each set with the same geohash value. However, I can only use area box determined by geohash prefix, and cannot provide custom radius (e.g. 5km, 2km, 1km, etc) value, which makes this query not so flexible.

```
select id, ST_GeoHash(way, 5), st_y(way) as lat, st_x(way) as lng 
from points order by st_geohash(way, 5) limit 1000;


id          geohash lat         lng
115319221   "4uusx" -41.5740949 -74.0718146
679361789   "4uusx" -41.5759059 -74.0728299
591844292   "4uusz" -41.5711773 -74.0703186
796302025   "4uutp" -41.5086211 -74.1087041
672159089   "4uuu8" -41.5721128 -74.0665036
687629681   "4uuub" -41.57108   -74.069856
591843790   "4uuub" -41.5696367 -74.064995
596950189   "4uuub" -41.5700602 -74.0660787
```

Comment: What have you tried? Editing the Question to include your code makes it easier to generate a solution that will work for you.

Comment: How about using `ST_Buffer` on each gas station's geometry and then a `ST_Intersects` on each of these buffers with the gas stations and a `LIMIT 1` to only return one gas station

Comment: If you can construct the query to select *ALL X*, then add a `LIMIT 1` to your query, with your rows optionally sorted if you don't want an apparently-random output.

However, if you mean to construct a query where you seek to find an area where at most only one entity meets your condition, that's a different kind of problem. Your two sample queries are illustrating both of these problems.

Comment: @Vince Thanks for feedback. I added a sample per suggestion.

Comment: @JoeBe, I did not think about that. That seems interesting. Though, if multiple gas stations's buffer zones are intersected, like a long chain in a line, the query may end up selling unnecessarily select only 1, while more than 1 could be selected. Still, I will think more about your approach.

Comment: @alphabetasoup I am sorry about the confusion. I have rephrased the sample scenario.

Comment: I was more talking about an intersect between gas stations and each buffer zone rather than between the buffer zones. So you have buffer zone `A` from gas station `A` and then your result of the intersection check could be gas station `B`, `C` and `E`, which you limit by only showing `B`.

Comment: Do you need to see the exact location pf one station, or is it acceptable to make an (e.g.) 500 meter raster and show if there is at least one station inside each 500x500m2 square?

Comment: Also, what is the approximate size of your data  set? Is it global or would it be possible to project it to  some meter or feet based projection?

Comment: Hm.. getting a raster would be o.k. as I can always make subsequent queries to pick one representative station. There are around millions of rows, and it is global data with geometry scattered across the world.

Comment: @JoeBe But if we do the same thing for Buffer zone B from station B, and buffer zone C from station C wouldn't the result set overlaps? How would I know which gas station to use & which to skip in the first place?

Comment: I think I was still not understanding it completely. So basically you display all stations with no other station intersecting its buffer zone. And for those gas stations you are having a intersection you just exclude the intersected gas stations in the query (e.g. by storing the intersection information in a seperate table `stations_in_buffer` and checking if gas station A is part of that table)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple way to cluster with `ST_SnapToGrid` is to use `DISTINCT ON`:

```
SELECT id, way FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT ON (snap) 
  id, way,
  ST_SnapToGrid(way, 1) AS snap 
FROM points
) AS t;
```

The precision value in `ST_SnapToGrid` is chosen based on required point density. This picks an essentially random point as the representative point for the cell.

For a limited extent make this faster by adding a WHERE clause:

```
SELECT id, way FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT ON (snap) 
  id, way,
  ST_SnapToGrid(way, 1) AS snap 
FROM points
WHERE way && ST_MakeEnvelope(xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax, 4326);
) AS t;
```

Alternatively, to add a count of the number of points in each cell you can use an aggregation approach.  (Note that the aggregated id value will only match the chosen point when the count = 1)

```
SELECT COUNT(1), MIN(id) AS name, 
  MIN(way)::geometry(point,4326) AS way,
  ST_X(snap) AS snapx, ST_Y(snap) AS snapy
FROM ( 
  SELECT id, way, ST_SnapToGrid(way, 1) AS snap
  FROM points
  --  WHERE way && ST_MakeEnvelope(-128.7275, 45.8855, -115.9615, 49.3854, 4326)
) AS t
GROUP BY snapx, snapy;
```

Comment: These queries are concise & beautiful. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the function `ST_SnapToGrid` to gather the points in "cells", of the size that depends on the parameters you give. Then you just have to use a `group by st_geohash(geom, 8) limit 1` (with `geom` the result of `ST_SnapToGrid`) to get the first by "cell" (the geohash size doesn't really matters, it is just to group more easily than using geometry, it just needs to be more precise than the snaptogrid). You could also add some randomness by adding a field `random()` and order your result by this field.

This would look like something like that:

```
WITH data_snapped AS 
(
    SELECT 
            id,
            random() as rng,
            ST_SnapToGrid(way::geometry, 10) as geom, -- Your precision here. Casted in geometry to have meters.
            ST_Y(way) as lat,
            ST_X(way) as lng 
        FROM 
            points
)
SELECT 
        DISTINCT ON (ST_geohash(geom)) 
        id,
        lat,
        lng
    FROM
        data_snapped
    ORDER BY
        ST_geohash(geom), rng;
```

I usually prefer to use geohash than geom to group or order, I think it's shorter (I'm not sure), but you should be able to use either.

Comment: `ST_SnapToGrid` might work for me. 1. Why do you have to group by geohash? Can't you group by `geom` itself since it has already been snapped previously? 2. Once you use `group by`, it won't be possible to select one particular station's id, lat, lng, will it?

Comment: I edited my answer to respond your question and because effectively it did not worked. A `distinct on`, like @dr_jts is better.